# Can I use ST-LINK (or clone) for programming non-ST ARM{7,9} and Cortex A chips?

Tags: programmer, st-link, cortex, arm9

Can I program non-ST ARM926 or ARM7TDMI and Cortex-A chips using ST-LINK and ST-LINK clone? I've searched ST's website and I haven't found anything about this. If no, what is the cheapest way to do this? Do you know a way that is cheaper than buying a J-LINK?

I've read [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/250664/218342) answer, but it does not cover ARM926 and Cortex-A chips. Specifically, I want to flash Allwinner-A13 CPU, Atmel AT91 series and i.MX6/i.MX233 series.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use ST-Link programmer for non-ST chips?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/250664/can-i-use-st-link-programmer-for-non-st-chips)

Comment: Thanks, I've already checked this one, I updated the question.

Comment: the stlink is swd for cortex-ms (And the swim thing on stm8).  It is not a full jtag for a full sized arm.  You can get jlink clones (not the little purple swd one that is also just swd) for like 10 bucks on ebay, or for around $15 you can get an ftdi breakout from adafruit that works just fine with openocd.  but that only gets you into the core then you need software for the flash, which is chip specific and you may have to do that part yourself or maybe openocd or some other tool supports one or more of the chips in question.

Comment: your allwinners and others like that then have their own different interfaces that dont necessarily require jtag, often they have a rom based xmodem or something like that or the board will have an sd card and you can load something on that and the hardware can boot off of that, etc.  your older armv4s and armv5s you most likely need jtag, although who knows, depends.

Comment: Just read the manual for the part, find out what the options are.  Look at the board, its documentation, etc.  If you are looking for push the green button gui tools, you are barking up the wrong tree here, pay for the eval board and whatever expensive software and dongles that go with it.  Or can roll up your sleeves and do it with a $15 thing and some google searches and/or spend an afternoon writing a tool.

Comment: If you want a one size fits all, an ftdi part with mpsse and openocd will provide access to a wide array of arm cores and some others, jtag, swd, etc.  The ftdi part can be used to generate just about any protocol so then it is just a small matter of programming to make it wiggle the lines in the right way.

Comment: @old_timer Why did you post all that as comments? Isn't that an answer?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers :)