# Can I use an ST-LINK of a Nucleo-mini board to program a black pill?

Tags: stm32, st-link, nucleo

I have a [Nucleo-l432kc](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-l432kc.html) board that I actually fried by accident touching one of the pins with my power supply probes while they shared the same ground during a risky test of mine.

Anyway the problem now is I can't find a replacement at the moment in my region and a shipment of Aliexpress would take some time I have some  Blackpills and Clone ST-LINKs lying around but using those clones have no mass storage or Virtual com port feature.

My question is, can I use the ST-LINK on my fried board somehow? I think the ST-LINK circuitry itself is working fine since the mass storage and the OpenOCD commands are working fine except that the CPU won't respond to uploading any code and is getting very hot once powered so I will need to disconnect its power.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/250664/can-i-use-st-link-programmer-for-non-st-chips

Comment: I know that I can use it the problem is unlike bigger Nucleo boards which have jumper pins and a stand alone snapping stlink. this one doesn't
 I need some help here

Comment: This small Nucleo boards do not support debugging external MCUs. Depending on your soldering skills you can desolder burned MCU and solder wires to original PA13 and PA14 pins. SWDIO signal is also on R20, SWCLK is only on tiny MCU pins.